# Psychopy: draw all images from a list at once

Tags: python, image, draw, psychopy

I have a list with 12 images. All of them have different locations (that is, they do not overlap at all). I want to draw them all at once. In other words, I want to see all 12 pictures at the same time on the screen. So far, I only got this:

```
    lines = [line1,line2,line3,line4,line5,line6
            line7,line8,line9,line10,line11,line12]

    for i in range(12):
        lines[i].draw()
```

But, of course, this code only draws one pic at a time, after I press any key. Is there then a way to draw the 12 pics at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code only drew one image at a time because of how the loop was set up -- it was (more or less) saying "For each element in `circles`, draw several things and flip the front and back buffers". Each time the buffers flip, unless you tell it otherwise via `win.flip(clearBuffer = False)`, the previous things on the screen are removed. To draw the images at the same time, you could just loop through the image list and call the `draw()` method on each element, e.g.:

```
for i in imglist:
    i.draw()

win.flip()
```

If you are willing to cede control over properties of individual images, one way would be to use [BufferImageStim](http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/bufferimagestim.html). This takes longer to initialize, but may be faster than drawing individual images (I haven't timed it properly). Both methods are demonstrated below.

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core
import urllib
import random

win = visual.Window([400, 400], fullscr = False)

# picture of a cat, save to file
urllib.urlretrieve('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/' + 
                   '07/c3/45/07c345d0eca11d0bc97c894751ba1b46.jpg', 'tmp.jpg')

# create five images with (probably) unique positions
imglist = [visual.ImageStim(win = win, image = 'tmp.jpg',
                            size = (.2, .2),
                            pos = ((random.random() - 0.5) * 2,
                                   (random.random() - 0.5) * 2))
           for i in xrange(5)]

# draw individual images
for i in imglist: 
    i.draw()

win.flip()

# wait for key press, then clear window
event.waitKeys()
win.flip()
core.wait(0.5)

# create aggregate stimulus (should look identical)
buffs = visual.BufferImageStim(win, stim = imglist)

buffs.draw()
win.flip()

event.waitKeys()

core.quit()
```

Comment: Awesome, both worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer!